# How to check if overall results from a survey are significantly affected by participation from a large company(ies)?

Tags: outliers, leverage

Suppose there is some sort of survey where people from various companies answer some questions.

Is it possible to determine whether overall results from the survey are significantly affected by answers from large companies? Or if the results don't really change with/without a large company.

I was thinking of doing something like testing whether observations from a particular company are influential or not. However, I'm not sure how to proceed as the response variable consists of several different questions, not just one (or an aggregate result).

How would I be able to identify whether a company is influential, and if it is, which questions is it influencing and by how much?